# How to insert data in DataWarehouse tables for early arriving facts ?What is the procedure to be followed?

Tags: data-warehouse, fact

I want to know how to insert data in data warehouse tables for early arriving facts ? What is the the procedure to be followed ?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be load them in a different table other than your fact table or load them into your fact table with an identifier (Kimball calls this method "hot partition") to reprocess them later, maybe with your regular batch.